# Returning distinct rows in SQLAlchemy with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy's [Query.distinct](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct) method is behaving inconsistently:

```
>>> [tag.name for tag in session.query(Tag).all()]
[u'Male', u'Male', u'Ninja', u'Pirate']
>>> session.query(Tag).distinct(Tag.name).count()
4
>>> session.query(Tag.name).distinct().count()
3
```

So the second form gives the correct result but the first form does not.  This appears to happen with SQLite but NOT with Postgres.  I have a function which is passed a query object to have a `distinct` clause applied to it, so it would be highly difficult to rewrite everything top use the second approach above.  Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

According to the docs:

> When present, the Postgresql dialect will render a DISTINCT ON
> (>) construct.

So, passing column expressions to `distinct()` works for PostgreSQL only (because there is `DISTINCT ON`).

In the expression `session.query(Tag).distinct(Tag.name).count()` sqlalchemy ignores `Tag.name` and produces the query (distinct on all fields):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag.country_id AS tag_country_id, tag.name AS tag_name 
FROM tag
```

As you said, in your case `distinct(Tag.name)` is applied - so instead of just `count()` consider using this:

```
session.query(Tag).distinct(Tag.name).group_by(Tag.name).count()
```

Comment: Thanks; I saw that comment in the docs about `DISTINCT ON` but since the docs didn't explicitly say 'and that's the only way that this works' or anything like it, I didn't realize that was implied.

Comment: Downvoted because promoting the SQLite specific extension, which allows selecting non-aggregate columns that are not determined by the GROUP BY clause, producing indeterminate results (well not exactly here because of the `count()`, but correct solutions exist, like in the other answer).

Comment: @IljaEverilä nice duplet downvote, totally by an accident.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the comment though, it's not often that happens with a downvote, but certainly a desired behavior. I didn't really promote anything here, just tried to help answering an *sqlite-specific question*.

Comment: Though this is horribly hindsighted, given you're answering an sqlite-specific question, why not drop the `distinct(Tag.name)` altogether, because it's useless in SQLite and the query as it is will be rejected by most SQL DBMS due to the grouping. On the double dv, I do share links to interesting q/a (one way or the other). This would make a nice dupe target, if not for the accepted answer, though you nicely explain why `distinct()` even accepts expressions as args.

Answer (score 50):

When you use `session.query(Tag)` you alway query for the whole `Tag` object, so if your table contains other columns it won't work.

Let's assume there is an `id` column, then the query

```
sess.query(Tag).distinct(Tag.name)
```

will produce:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag.id AS tag_id, tag.name AS tag_name FROM tag
```

The argument to the distinct clause is ignored completely.

If you really only want the distinct names from the table, you must explicitly select only the names:

```
sess.query(Tag.name).distinct()
```

produces:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag.name AS tag_name FROM tag
```