# python sqlalchemy distinct column values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 6 tables in my SQLite database, each table with 6 columns(`Date, user, NormalA, specialA, contact, remarks`) and 1000+ rows.

How can I use sqlalchemy to sort through the Date column to look for duplicate dates, and delete that row?

Comment: Q1: do you have also a separate primary key column? Q2: Why is the fact that you have **6** tables important for this question?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is your model:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    user = Column(String)
    # do not really care of columns other than `id` and `date`
    # important here is the fact that `id` is a PK
```

following are two ways to delete you data:

1. Find duplicates, mark them for deletion and commit the transaction
2. Create a single SQL query which will perform deletion on the database directly.

For both of them a helper sub-query will be used:

```
# helper subquery: find first row (by primary key) for each unique date
subq = (
    session.query(MyTable.date, func.min(MyTable.id).label("min_id"))
    .group_by(MyTable.date)
) .subquery('date_min_id')
```

**Option-1: Find duplicates, mark them for deletion and commit the transaction**

```
# query to find all duplicates
q_duplicates = (
    session
    .query(MyTable)
    .join(subq, and_(
        MyTable.date == subq.c.date,
        MyTable.id != subq.c.min_id)
    )
)

for x in q_duplicates:
    print("Will delete %s" % x)
    session.delete(x)
session.commit()
```

**Option-2: Create a single SQL query which will perform deletion on the database directly**

```
sq = (
    session
    .query(MyTable.id)
    .join(subq, and_(
        MyTable.date == subq.c.date,
        MyTable.id != subq.c.min_id)
    )
).subquery("subq")

dq = (
    session
    .query(MyTable)
    .filter(MyTable.id.in_(sq))
).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: What is 'Base' or what does it stand for in the Class? This code is not runnable without defining it.

Comment: @Apostolos, please see the [Declarative Mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_styles.html) part of documentation. Base is the base class for mapped classes/tables.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the [Find duplicate values in SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) this might help you to select duplicate dates:

```
query = session.query(
    MyTable
).\
    having(func.count(MyTable.date) > 1).\
    group_by(MyTable.date).all()
```

If you only want to show unique dates; [`distinct on`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223174/returning-distinct-rows-in-sqlalchemy-with-sqlite) is what you might need

Comment: Cant do a `func.count`. There doesn't seem to be that choice

Comment: @jakewong Did you import the function: `from sqlalchemy import func`?

Answer (score 1):

While I like the whole object oriented approache with SQLAlchemy, sometimes I find it easier to directly use some SQL.
And since the records don't have a key, we need the row number (`_ROWID_`) to delete the targeted records and I don't think the API provides it.

So first we connect to the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db = create_engine(r'sqlite:///C:\temp\example.db')
eng = db.engine
```

Then to list all the records:

```
for row in eng.execute("SELECT * FROM TableA;") :
  print row
```

And to display all the duplicated records where the dates are identical:

```
for row in eng.execute("""
  SELECT * FROM {table}
  WHERE {field} IN (SELECT {field} FROM {table} GROUP BY {field} HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
  ORDER BY {field};
  """.format(table="TableA", field="Date")) :
  print row
```

Now that we identified all the duplicates, they probably need to be fixed if the other fields are different:

```
eng.execute("UPDATE TableA SET NormalA=18, specialA=20 WHERE Date = '2016-18-12' ;");
eng.execute("UPDATE TableA SET NormalA=4,  specialA=8  WHERE Date = '2015-18-12' ;");
```

And finnally to keep the first inserted record and delete the most recent duplicated records :

```
print eng.execute("""
  DELETE FROM {table} 
  WHERE _ROWID_ NOT IN (SELECT MIN(_ROWID_) FROM {table} GROUP BY {field});
  """.format(table="TableA", field="Date")).rowcount
```

Or to keep the last inserted record and delete the other duplicated records :

```
print eng.execute("""
  DELETE FROM {table} 
  WHERE _ROWID_ NOT IN (SELECT MAX(_ROWID_) FROM {table} GROUP BY {field});
  """.format(table="TableA", field="Date")).rowcount
```