# flask-sqlalchemy query multiple rows that has different value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I trying to get 2 rows from first, but it should be has different value.

For example,

```
class Table(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(primary_key)
    category = db.Column(string)
    user_id = db.Column(Integer, Foreign(User))

two_rows = Table.query.filter_by(category='category1').limit(2).all()
```

With above code, we can get two rows. But it never ensure that each row has different user_id.
How can I ensure (or do query) it?

So I expect the result

Rather than

```
[
<Table id=1, category='category1', user_id=1>, 
<Table id=2, category='category1', user_id=1>
]
```

It should be

```
[
<Table id=1, category='category1', user_id=1>, 
<Table id=3, category='category1', user_id=2>
]
```

[+] I'm currently using

- postgresql
- flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the query to 2 results with distinct user_ids, simply use `distinct()`

```
two_rows = Table.query.filter_by(category='category1').distinct(Table.user_id).limit(2).all()
```

more precisions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223174/returning-distinct-rows-in-sqlalchemy-with-sqlite), [there](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct), and of course [the basics here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)